# How to print to a J text box the entire contents of a tree map?

Tags: java, swing

Hi Everyone thanks for taking the time to look at my question.

I would like to use the JText field I have created to display the values of a tree map which contains all the employees: ID numbers (as the key in the map)as well as an Employee object which contains a to string method of all the employee details.

the system seems to be working fine because when I print to the console (CMD) it works fine and prints out all the values in the MAP but when I try print it to a JText box it only prints one object (one employee) from the entire list.

I believe the issue lies with my for loop i am using to access all the details.

the issue lies with this line of code:

```
writeStrings.setText(writeStrings.getText()+" "+dEmp);
```

This is the code in its entirety:

```
public void chooseEmpToAdd()
{


     JFrame frameAllEmps = new JFrame();
      frameAllEmps.setSize( 450, 140 );
     frameAllEmps.pack();
     frameAllEmps.setVisible(true); 


    int x = 0;
    System.out.println("ALL Emps from the tree map");
    for(int key:employeeMap.keySet())
    {
        JTextField writeStrings;
        writeStrings = new JTextField(20);
        Employee dEmp = employeeMap.get(key);
        System.out.println("Employe no :" +x+": "+dEmp);
        writeStrings.setText(writeStrings.getText()+" "+dEmp);
        frameAllEmps.add(writeStrings); 
         x++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Building a string by concatenating like that in a loop is bad practice : it creates tons of new String instances. Use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
writeStrings = new JTextField(20);
```

You create *new* JTextField component on every iteration and add it to container.
JFrame uses BorderLayout as a default layout.
This layout puts your JTextField component in the center (frameAllEmps.add(writeStrings)). So you lost previous added JTextField and see only last JTextField component.